# IE 11 memory leak with static HTML, no JS

Tags: memory-leaks, internet-explorer-11

I have a huge react app which causes very heavy memory usage in IE11, it will eventually lock up.  I am testing memory usage in IE11 using the memory tab in the developer tools.  It is showing increases in memory for every single page refresh.  Using methods like window.CollectGarbage() do nothing at all, memory usage stays the same.

Now what really stumps me is that I created a blank HTML page with no CSS, no JS and watched the memory tab when I refreshed the page over and over.  The memory started at about 80MB and got to over 200MB before I got bored of clicking refresh.  How can this be?  This seems to suggest its just the browser itself and it will eventually use up all of a systems RAM not matter what you do?...

Is this true?  Is there a way to have a SPA in IE11 that can be used all day without issue?  Any way to reset the RAM usage besides launching a new window?

Comment: You’d have to see exactly what the SPA is doing as browsers don’t do that on their own, even one as bad as IE.

Comment: Try to refer these links may give some idea about the issue. Ref: https://medium.com/@garthw/how-to-work-around-ie-memory-leaks-in-spas-b2f6bc7c9ae9 and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12231/Memory-Leakage-in-Internet-Explorer-Revisited

Comment: @NickM As i said, it happens with static HTML, not JS at all.

Comment: Actually I am thinking this is a bug with the memory tool itself.  Without it open and only watching the windows resource monitor I get normal behavior with what looks like garbage collection.  Ram spikes and goes down with each refresh.  Open the memory tab though and RAM just keeps climbing.

Comment: Try another one? or maybe there's some extension or something like that?